# Changing Android Studio Emulator from localhost:port to 192.168.x.x

Tags: wi-fi, android-emulator, android-studio

I am trying to figure out how to change Android Studio's Emulator so that it can be reached from a different IP from the host machine. Currently I can access it at localhost:5554. I am trying to start a listener on port 64006 of the emulator but anything I send to that port from my host machine doesn't reach the Android because it is running on port 5554 and listening on port 64006 within that.

Comment: I am not sure if emulator allows to open the adb port on a public interface. Instead you could simply use `socat` to forward a TCP port from your ethernet interface to the emulator localhost port.

Comment: If you found a good solution you can answer your own question (not only comment on it). Based on your description this sound interesting also for other people.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I was able to fix this issue by doing the following:

1. Telnet onto the emulator (telnet localhost portNum)
2. Auth using the auth command and token in your user folder (.emulator_console_auth_token)
3. Use the redir command once authenticated "redir add tcp:123:456" (This command says to send anything destined for host port 123 to port 456 on the android emulator)